# Django send welcome email after User created using signals

Tags: email, django-signals, django-1.11

I have a create_user_profile signal and I'd like to use same signal to send a welcome email to the user.

This is what I wrote so far in my **signals.py**:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()

    subject = 'Welcome to MyApp!'
    from_email = 'no-reply@myapp.com'
    to = instance.email
    plaintext = get_template('email/welcome.txt')
    html = get_template('email/welcome.html')

    d = Context({'username': instance.username})

    text_content = plaintext.render(d)
    html_content = html.render(d)

    try:
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        msg.send()
    except BadHeaderError:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
```

This is failing with this error:

```
TypeError at /signup/
context must be a dict rather than Context.
```

pointing to the forms.save in my views.py file.
Can you help me to understand what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On django 1.11 the template context must be a dict:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render

Try to just remove the Context object creationg.

```
d = {'username': instance.username}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a dict to the render instead of a Context object

```
d = {'username': instance.username}
text_content = plaintext.render(d)
```